# How to change color of an app?

Tags: applications, apk

I don't know programming,but I know that we can change color of an app by going to res>>values>>color and editing it there with the app
"apk editor".

But this app is not working now.
when i click "build" it shows this error message:

> invalid resource directory name: /data/user/0/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor/files/decoded/res navigation
> invalid resource directory name: /data/user/0/com.gmail.heagoo.apkeditor/files/decoded/res font>

Notice that this error message shows up even if i don't make any changes. Even if I just open an apk and press build, this error message pops up.

So, is this a problem with the application?
What should i do?
How can i change color of an app?

Comment: It seems that the APK file you want to edit is not supported by "apk editor". May be you should just talk to the developer of "apk editor"?

Comment: Wasn't your identical question closed earlier this morning? This seems to have been submitted as Q#237025 [closed], and now again as Q#237026.

Comment: I asked for suggesting an app in that question. That is why it was closed. But even after  i edited out that sentence , the question was not reopened. I think it take some time to reopen that question. So, I posted this question. However this cannot be considered a duplicate because i edited the first question to "This was deleted" because there was no option to delete that question

Comment: `res>>values>>color` isn't the only place to save colors. A developer can hard-code the colors e.g. in `styles.xml` or may change dynamically from Java code. So there's no general answer to your question. Ask the developer or reverse-engineer the app fully and dig it out yourself. // Regarding the error you're getting, again, there is no universally working solution for all apps to decompile and recompile them. Developer may use some obfuscation method which makes it impossible or very difficult to de/re-compile the app.

Comment: @Irfan Latif Ok,thanks